# How to get the number of words in Jquery form validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

It is tag input box validation.A poster can combine multiple words into single-words, space is used to separate tags. I use Jquery form validation plugin to validate the form. I need to add a customized method to validate the tag input box.
This is the code:

```
 $.validator.addMethod("tagcheck", function(value, element) { 
     return value && value.split(" ").length < 4;

    }, "Please input at most 3 tags.");
```

But what if there are two spaces between two adjacent words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a  regular expression to [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Split) your string:

```
$.validator.addMethod("tagcheck", function(value, element) { 
  return value && value.split(/\s+/).length < 4;
}, "Please input at most 3 tags.");
```

`\s+` Will match one or more  white space characters, including space, tab, form feed, line feed.

Comment: ye `CMS` is the new Jon Skeet ;)